# Can not construct instance of abstract type when using resteasy

Tags: java, jackson, wildfly, resteasy

I have a class which extends an abstract class XjafAgent, and that abstract class implements an interface called Agent.

I execute the following code on an application which is running on Wildfly and utilizing the resteasy library:

```
ResteasyClient client = new ResteasyClientBuilder().build();
ResteasyWebTarget rtarget = client.target(url);
ConnectionManagerRestAPI rest = rtarget.proxy(ConnectionManagerRestAPI.class);
rest.moveAgent(getAgentReference(aid));
```

My REST API method title moveAgent is defined as follows:

```
public void moveAgent(Agent agent);
```

So it expects to get something that implements the Agent interface (which is a class that extends my XjafAgent abstract class). However, when I execute this code I get the following error:

```
problem: abstract types either need to be mapped to concrete types, have custom deserializer, or be instantiated with additional type information
```

Now, I found that by adding the following line of code to the abstract class solved the problem for some:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use=JsonTypeInfo.Id.CLASS, include=JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property="@class")
```

I tried adding this annotation to both my XjafAgent abstract class as well as my Agent interface to no avail.

So the main issue is that I am not sending an object of a concrete class, but rather my method is accepting an object that implements the given interface. Any idea how I can fix this? I'm open to any suggestions.

Comment: But of course you *are* sending an object of a concrete class, since you cannot get your hands on any other kind.  The method signature just doesn't specify which class -- and therein lies the problem.  The remote side doesn't need to know the implementation class to invoke methods on the object, but it *does* need to know how to deserialize the object from the request.

Comment: And how do I supply this information?